# NA returned by approxfun() function R

Tags: r, interpolation, distribution

```
obs=log(rexp(500))
plot(density(obs))
```

[image]

I am using the [`approxfun()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/approxfun.html) R function to create a function capturing this distribution and able to return a `y` value for any `x` value passed (by using interpolation).

```
fun=approxfun(density(obs)$y)
# create a sequence of x values
seq=round(seq(min(obs),max(obs),length.out=50),2)
# find out which y values assigned by fun are not equal to NA
seq[-which(is.na(fun(seq)))]
```

returns

```
1.11 1.27 1.43 1.60
```

**Why are all `x` values below 1 (from `-6.38 to 0.95` to be exact) passed to the function all assigned a `NA` `y` value?** The function is defined for `-6, -2` etc? I would have expected interpolated values around `0, 0.13`, etc. Not `NAs`...

Comment: you are basically trying to do a linear interpolation with only one vector of data ... check https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/approxfun.html

Comment: woah, I really need to get some sleep. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
fun <- approxfun(density(obs))
```

You don't supply the x-values when you write `fun=approxfun(density(obs)$y)`. So, you should just omit the `$y`.

Hence:

```
obs <- log(rexp(500))
fun <- approxfun(density(obs))
seq <- round(seq(min(obs), max(obs), length.out = 50), 2)
seq[-which(is.na(fun(seq)))]
# numeric(0)
```

yields no `NA`s.

Comment: hum, interesting let me try